# Using fields from a playlist file and using them as arguments for a command

Tags: shell-script, awk

Example contents of the playlist file:

```
1. The fire is on - 03:50
2. Abc dge khji kkt mmy kdj - 09:20
3. Blowing in the winds  - 14:16
4. By the rivers of Babylon - 15:46
5. Waka waka it's time for africa - 20:30
6. DGF djf Kmf pffg jdkf dhf - 28:25
7. Fdsa djf | kf |- 34:25
8. Despacito despatico - 41:33
...
...
...
```

The command - `ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "b" -to "c" "output"`

Now from the list, the contents from the beginning (i.e from the serial no.) till the end of the text line (which may include pipes as well) should be the last argument of the command (in the position of 'output'), the timestamp at the end should be the argument for parameter -ss and the timestamp in the next line should be the argument of parameter `-to`

This is quite similiar to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570344/332496) but i am quite not sure how to modify the awk command to suit this particular case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact output you want to get from the input you posted. get rid of the `...` lines from your input as they just make it untestable.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the `awk` script from the [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570344/332496):

```
awk -v input="a" -v to_last="55:55" '
  BEGIN {
    str="ffmpeg -i \"%s\" -ss \"%s\" -to \"%s\" \"%s\"\n"
  }
  NR>1 {
    printf str, input, ss, $NF, output
  }
  {
    ss=$NF                       # last field is the `ss` field
    $NF=""                       # clear last field
    output=$0                    # set the remaining line to output
    sub(/[-| \t]+$/, "", output) # remove blanks, `-` and `|` at the end of output
  }
  END{
    printf str, input, ss, to_last, output
  }
' playlist
```

Output (if you remove the `...` lines from the playlist):

```
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "03:50" -to "09:20" "1. The fire is on"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "09:20" -to "14:16" "2. Abc dge khji kkt mmy kdj"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "14:16" -to "15:46" "3. Blowing in the winds"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "15:46" -to "20:30" "4. By the rivers of Babylon"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "20:30" -to "28:25" "5. Waka waka it's time for africa"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "28:25" -to "34:25" "6. DGF djf Kmf pffg jdkf dhf"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "34:25" -to "41:33" "7. Fdsa djf | kf"
ffmpeg -i "a" -ss "41:33" -to "55:55" "8. Despacito despatico"
```

Comment: could you give brief explantion of the command ? especially the -F flag and the sub() method. What is happening inside the sub method ?

Comment: The `-F` sets the input field separator (variable `FS`) used to split each record into fields. The separator splits each line into `$1` and `$2` (the name and `ss`/`to`). See [Specifying How Fields Are Separated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) (GNU Awk manual)

Comment: The [`sub(regexp, replacement [, target])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-formatting-strings)
function is used to remove blank characters (tabs, spaces) from the end of the first field `$1`, i.e. one or more blank characters at the end of the field (regex `[[:blank:]]+$`) are replaced with an empty string `""`.

Comment: That would fail if any of the titles contained `<blank>-<blank>`, e.g. [Undone - The Sweater Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHQqqM5sr7g) by Weezer, and the `ffmpeg` command it generates would fail when executed if the title contained anything the shell could interpret, e.g. `$1`.

Comment: @EdMorton I removed the file separator and used the last field as you did. The double quotes are a feature request, not a bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something like this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    fmt = "ffmpeg -i \047a\047 -ss \047%s\047 -to \047%s\047 \047%s\047\n"
}
NR > 1 {
    printf fmt, beg, $NF, title
}
{
    beg = $NF
    title = $0
}
END {
    printf fmt, beg, "forever?", title
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '03:50' -to '09:20' '1. The fire is on - 03:50'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '09:20' -to '14:16' '2. Abc dge khji kkt mmy kdj - 09:20'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '14:16' -to '15:46' '3. Blowing in the winds  - 14:16'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '15:46' -to '20:30' '4. By the rivers of Babylon - 15:46'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '20:30' -to '28:25' '5. Waka waka it's time for africa - 20:30'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '28:25' -to '34:25' '6. DGF djf Kmf pffg jdkf dhf - 28:25'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '34:25' -to '41:33' '7. Fdsa djf | kf |- 34:25'
ffmpeg -i 'a' -ss '41:33' -to 'forever?' '8. Despacito despatico - 41:33'
```

but without seeing your expected output it's just a guess.

Not the use of singe instead of double quotes in the output - that's very important so that when you execute the `ffmpeg` commands later the shell doesn't first interpret the text within the quotes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.